# How to retrieve state from local storage on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Guys is there anyway to get the state from localstorage?

I Read some articles and some questions here, but none helps, how Could I load my state saved on the local storage?
I Don't want to set the state field by field, there's a lot of it, but I have 3 components that has functions of previous and next , 
so on the previous I want to load the state to be the same of that session.

I'm trying this:

```
  var JSON1= JSON.stringify(this.state)
  localStorage.setItem('JSON1', JSON1)
```

And on the constructor

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let JSONSTOR = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("JSON1"))
    var newST = this.state
    newST = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("JSONCLIENTE 1"));
    this.setState(newST)
```

}

But it's not working, is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Post the link to your code in github

Answer (score 2):

As Fernando Ramirez suggested, you could use Redux. Redux also takes a state parameter so you can set the initial state. There are examples of how to save Redux state to localStorage and then also re-load it from localStorage. Here's a [tutorial from the creator of Redux Dan Abramov](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage).

The thing you are trying to do looks correct, you just have some mistakes in your flow.

This should work for your case:

```
var JSON1 = JSON.stringify(this.state);

localStorage.setItem("JSON1", JSON1);
```

And then in your constructor you can reload the state from localStorage:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("JSON1"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this could be using Redux. With Redux you can handler the global state of your app.

Here's Redux official documantation:

[Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily load [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) data into React using the lifecycle method [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

```
componentDidMount() {
  // Load localStorage data into state (if it exists)
  let data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("yourData"));
  if (data) {
    this.setState(data);
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that the data retrieved from `localStorage` is a string that should have an object like appearance, this way you can convert it into a valid object with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), this in turns allows you to successfully set the local state in the React app.

Working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/saving-state-to-localstorage-txm7x)